# multiple queries / level

Tags: database-design

I am making a referral system, and it needs to have multiple (up to 10) levels. So basically when someone signs up, it will set them at a referral id. So I need to be able to add up to 10 levels in the levels table, then display all the referrals for those levels. If you dont understand, ask and I'll try explaining it better.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "levels". Could you perhaps explain what a level is?

Comment: How do we determine the 10 referrals?   I think you need to give a scenario and also your problem .

Comment: cdeszaq, okay well. I have a table called levels. It allows me to add rows in it for refs. Say I have 3 rows in it. Id's are: 1, 2, and 3. Then, I want to echo all referrals a logged in user has with up to 3 levels. Does that page sense?

Comment: For cdeszaq and Amir s, I posted this for blindy: "OK. I have a better way to explain it lol. K, so this is how it works. Level's work like this: Level 1 would be all the referrals I referred to the website. Level 2 would be all the referrals of the user I referred and so on. See what im saying?"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want 2 tables, `users` and `referrals`.

`users` has `userid` (PK) and other user data, like name and stuff.

`referrals` has `refid` (PK), `userid` (FK), `useridref` (FK) and referral data.

When you need to see what referrals a user has, you do something like `SELECT * FROM referrals WHERE userid=?`.

edit: OK so I finally get the levels now. In the general case you'd need a recursive query, but if you only want to test for one level at a time, you can do it like this:

```
select usersreferred.* 
from referrals r1                                   -- level 1
  inner join referrals r2 on r1.useridref=r2.userid -- level 2
  inner join referrals r3 on r2.useridref=r3.userid -- level 3
  inner join users usersreferred on usersreferred.userid=r3.useridref
where r1.userid=?
```

You have to manually build the join query string, but that's the general idea. Given a user id, that query will show you all the level 3 users that got referenced to the site by the selected user.

Comment: yeah exactly. Thing is, how do I know which level? Because, the problem is, I never know how many levels their gonna be. For example, I could do your example 3 times for 3 levels. But, I have no way of knowing how many levels are inside the levels table.

Comment: @Justin, what's this level thing? Just the count? You can get that with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM referrals WHERE userid=?`

Comment: Blindy, OK. I have a better way to explain it lol. K, so this is how it works. Level's work like this: Level 1 would be all the referrals I referred to the website. Level 2 would be all the referrals of the user I referred and so on. See what im saying?

Comment: @Blindy, OK cool nice. The problem is, I dont have a referrals table at the moment lol.. theres a levels table and accounts table :/

Comment: @Blindy, when I do: select *
from accounts r1
  inner join members r2 on r1.id = r2.id 
  inner join members r3 on r2.id = r3.id 
  inner join members members on members.id=r3.id
where r1.id='$aid' I am outputted with my username and not my referrals..

Comment: @Justin, you need at least 3 ID's in your referrals table: the referral row id (unique key), the user id that did the referring (foreign key) and the user id that got referred (foreign key). Read through my code again.

Comment: `--` indicates a comment in SQL.

Comment: @Justin,"Not working" is not descriptive. What have you tried? What do your tables look like? What data is in them? What's your query? Are you getting errors? The wrong answer? What wrong answer? etc.